# Date field in view Filter Criteria, where date may be blank

Tags: views, datetime

I have a date field attached to a content type and it's not a required field. I want to use this date to control the display of the content using a view and it's filter criteria.

Some content may have blank dates and some may have a start and end date.

Is there a way I can set up the view to check for all of these conditions?

- content is published
- AND content type is TYPE
- AND Start date is blank OR Start date is not blank AND start date is <= NOW
- AND End date is blank OR End date is not blank AND end date >= NOW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions I had set above were too many

- content is published
- AND content type is TYPE
- AND Start date is blank OR Start date is not blank AND start date is <= NOW
- AND End date is blank OR End date is not blank AND end date >= NOW

and should have been:

- content is published
- AND content type is TYPE
- AND Start date is blank OR start date is <= NOW
- AND End date is blank OR end date >= NOW

because the NOT blank is implied.

Using the 'And/Or, Rearrange' feature of the Filter Criteria, I was able to create 3 groups joined by AND's with Group 2 and 3 joined by OR's. Like so:

[image]

Comment: What settings did you use to check for a blank date?  I don't see an "is empty" operator in the date filter?

Comment: Content Offer Dates - start date and Content Offer Dates - end date:value2 are the conditions that check for empty.

Comment: Thanks for response!  Turns out I was using the Date filter (which does not have an empty option) instead of the regular field filter.

Comment: Giles: Built-in date fields like "User: Last Access" don't have field counterparts, so for those instances I was able to use Date: is not between MIN: 1000-01-01 / MAX: 3000-01-01 which successfully shows me all users who have never access the site.